# Newton's Method derivation from Taylor series

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion, newton-raphson

I was reading Networn's Method of Optimization in the book `"An Introduction to optimization" by Chong Zak`. The text shows the Taylor polynomial expansion of $f(x)$ on $x_{k}$. Then it claims $q^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)}) = f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})$

> We assume now that at each measurement point $x^{(k)}$ we can calculate $f(x^{(k)}), f^{\prime}(x^{(k)}),f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})$. We can fit a quadratic function through $x^{(k)}$ that matches its first and second derivative with that of function $f$. This quadratic has the form 
>   $$g(x) = f(x^{(k)})+f^{\prime}(x^{(k)})(x-x^{(k)})+\frac{1}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})(x-x^{(k)})^2$$
>
> Note that $q(x^{(k)})=f(x^{(k)})$, $q^{\prime}(x^{(k)})=f^{\prime}(x^{(k)})$, $q^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})=f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})$

I can verify the first two. But for the last one I am getting $q^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})=2f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})$. I think I am wrong somewhere.

$$
q^{\prime}(x) = f^{\prime}(x^{(k)})+f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})(x-x^{(k)})+f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})(x-x^{(k)})+\frac{1}{2}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})(x-x^{(k)})^{2}\\
= f^{\prime}(x^{(k)})+2f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})(x-x^{(k)})+\frac{1}{2}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})(x-x^{(k)})^{2}\\
q^{\prime\prime}(x) = 2f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})+2(x-x^{(k)})f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x^{(k)}) + \dots
$$

So $q^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)}) = 2f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})$ . I am not getting where I am missing.

I think something is wrong, unless we drop the 3rd term from $g(x)$ we cannot have the 3rd claim.

Comment: What's the definition of $q$? The third term in $g(x)$ should be $\frac12 f''(x^{(k)})(x - x^{(k)})^2$.

Comment: Updated question with definition of $q$. Thanks the 3rd term was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Hmm. It was a stupid question. I am differentiating $f^{\prime}(x^{(k)})$ and producing $f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})$ which is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the variable is $x$, but $x^{(k)}$ is constant

therefore $g'(x)=f'(x^{(k)})+f''(x^{(k)})(x-x^{(k)})$ and $g'(x^{(k)})=f'(x^{(k)})$

$g''(x)=f''(x^{(k)})$ is constant

Comment: I can verify the first two claims. But cannot verify the last one.

Comment: @NeelBasu your verification was wrong, you did not have the right $g'$ because you treated $x^{(k)}$ as a variable

Comment: Hmm. It was a stupid question. I am differentiating $f^{\prime}(x^{(k)})$ and producing $f^{\prime\prime}(x^{(k)})$ which is a constant.